# how to intent from Fragmet to Fragment with his parent?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

Fragment1 have a different parent with Fragment2, actually i want to intent in Fragment2 with his parent.

```
Fragment2 fragment = new Fragment2().getParentFragment();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.containerView,fragment);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: `intent` does not play a part in FragmentTransaction . You can pass data using `#setArguments(Bundle bundle)`. What exactly is your question here? Its unclear right now .

Comment: my position is on fragment1 with parent mainActivity, i want to go to fragment2 with parent SecondActivity,

Comment: then you need to start SecondActivity with Intent Flags

Comment: i bring bundle for Fragment2, when i intent to SecondActivity it will be null pointer

Answer (score 0):

you must pass data to secondActivity by intent and then use setData method to pass data to fragment. Note you must do this in the onCreateView function in the fragment. Like below code:

```
public void setData(Data data){
this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
Bundle savedInstanceState){
  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout,container,false);


  // use data here
  // also use view components(like buttons) here 


  return rootView;
}
```